# Spring Boot application POST /api/recipe/new should respond with status code 200, responded: 404

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, http-status-code-404

Here is Spring boot application "Recipes". We can add a recipe on endpoint /api/recipe/new, also we can get recipe by id on endpoint /api/recipe/{id}. In this case we're using HashMap as a storage.

This is the Recipe class:

```
package recipes;

import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class Recipe {

    private String name;
    private String description;
    private String[] ingredients;
    private String[] directions;
}
```

This is the RestController

```
package recipes;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.server.ResponseStatusException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class RecipeRestController {

    int id = 0;
    Map<Integer, Recipe> recipeBook = new HashMap<>();

    @PostMapping(path = "/recipe/new", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
    public Integer adding(@RequestBody Recipe recipe) {
        if (!recipeBook.containsValue(recipe)) {
            recipeBook.put(++id, recipe);
        }
        return id;
    }

    @GetMapping("/recipe/{id}")
    public Recipe retrieving(@PathVariable int id) {
        Recipe recipe = recipeBook.get(id);
        if (recipe == null) {
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "Not found");
        }
        return recipe;
    }
}
```

The Main class is here

```
package recipes;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class RecipesApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RecipesApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Test request is JSON

```
{
   "name": "Fresh Mint Tea",
   "description": "Light, aromatic and refreshing beverage, ...",
   "ingredients": ["boiled water", "honey", "fresh mint leaves"],
   "directions": ["Boil water", "Pour boiling hot water into a mug", "Add fresh mint leaves", "Mix and let the mint leaves seep for 3-5 minutes", "Add honey and mix again"]
}
```

**Although it's pretty simple application I can't understand where is the problem...**

Comment: Please add your test request.

Comment: You don't include the way you test, how is header of request? Do you specify consumer/producer to application/json ... in your test request? Does web application run normally with other endpoint...

Comment: is this a hyperskill project Recipes?

Comment: Yeah. It is. May be you know where is my problem)

Comment: Huy, no with the rest of endpoints the same

Comment: The problem is gone. I had to send JSON object with one field "id" instead of sending Integer value. However thank you all